# Partitioning or separating a very large table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a very large table in mysql with 500,000,000 records in it with 100 requests ( `SELECT` ) per second.
This is schema:

```
id(int), 
user_id (int), 
content(text), 
date(datetime)
```

Since up to 90% of requests are within last 6 months. My question is about increasing performance.
Is it a good idea to separate those records from last 6 month in another table and SELECT from it, OR a partitioning method to get all records of the last 6 month fast.

Or if there's a better way...

For instance, a query is this.

```
SELECT content,user_id FROM log
JOIN users ON users.id = log.user_id
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
LIMIT 15
```

user_id, date is indexed in table `Log`
There are 2 million users in table `Users`.

Comment: How will you handle the other 10% if you gonna split table? Espessialy, when date range would fall into both timeframes, so one table couldn't cover it.

Comment: How about MERGE Storage Engine??

Comment: Do you have an index on date?

Comment: yes, I have an index on date, but it still takes too long to read. 10 seconds for a simple select.

Comment: @Alexander I think I can write in two tables for each insertion. and create an EVENT on secondary table to automatically deletes records with date > 6 month, what do you think?

Comment: well, that actually could do.

Comment: It will help us answer this question if you show the `SELECT` queries you are running at 100x per second, and if you show the indexes you have on the table.

Comment: I would first (if you haven't already) take a copy of the table, remove the older records and see if that improves your select time. That will eliminate other possibilities.

Comment: 500 million of that is very large? Only with hugh text, or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit says you use queries like this at a rate of a third of a million per hour.

```
 SELECT content,user_id 
   FROM log
   JOIN users ON users.id = log.user_id
  WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
  LIMIT 15
```

I will take the liberty of rewriting this query to fully qualify your column selections.

```
 SELECT log.content,
        log.user_id 
   FROM log                                  /* one half gigarow table */
   JOIN users ON users.id = log.user_id      /* two megarow table */
  WHERE log.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
  LIMIT 15
```

(Please consider updating your question if this is not correct.)

Why are you joining the `users` table in this query? None of your results seem to come from it. Why won't this query do what you need?

```
 SELECT log.content,
        log.user_id 
   FROM log                                  /* one half gigarow table */
  WHERE log.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY)
  LIMIT 15
```

If you want to make this query faster, put a compound covering index on `(date,user_id, content)`. This covering index will support a range scan and fast retrieval. If your `content` column is in fact of type TEXT (a LOB) type, you need to put just `(date,user_id)` into the covering index, and your retrieval will be a little slower.

Are you using the `JOIN` to ensure that you get log entries returned which have a matching entry in `users?`  If so, please explain your query better.

You definitely can partition your table based on date ranges. But you will need to either alter your table, or recreate and repopulate it, which will incur either downtime or a giant scramble.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-range.html

Something like this DDL should then do the trick for you

```
CREATE TABLE LOG (
  id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  /*maybe BIGINT? */
  user_id    INT NOT NULL,
  `date`     DATETIME NOT NULL,
  content    TEXT,
  UNIQUE KEY (id, `date`),
  KEY covering (`date`,user_id)
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(`date`) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-01-01'),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-07-01'),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-01'),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-07-01'),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01'),
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-07-01'),
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01'),
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-07-01')
);
```

Notice that there's some monkey business about the `UNIQUE KEY`. The column that goes into your partitioning function needs also to appear in the so-called primary key.

Later on, when July 2015 (partition `p7`'s cutoff date) draws near, you can run this statement to add a partition for the next six month segment of time.

```
   ALTER TABLE `log` 
 ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-01-01'))
```

But, seriously, none of this partitioning junk is going to help much if your queries have unnecessary joins or poor index coverage. And it is going to make your database administration more complex.

Comment: well, I `join` `users` table to get information of each row's user_id from `users` table. In fact, Im not sure `SELECT & JOIN` together is faster or `SELECT user_id,content FROM log` to populate a list of users_ids, then do another `SELECT information FROM users` to get those `users` information.

Comment: Can you do that in application? Depends on user count, but most of my apps have a regularly updated cache of users by ID because they are STATIC (the cache hits the db when an id is not in the cache). No need to push that stuff to the db - but that hughely depends on the type of users you have (facebook is different from a smaller company accounting system). I do that with a lot of static lookup data (some of it a million rows long).

Comment: So, you didn't show an example of an actual query you run? If you had dozens of rows, it wouldn't matter. What is the purpose of `LIMIT 15`? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Because you're in the gigarow range all this matters a lot.

Comment: no, I wrote my query, I have more than 500 million rows. i mentioned in my last comment of this post, I do not know the differences. you mean I should never join for such a large table like this?

Comment: There's no such thing as *never*. Indexes on both tables matter if you are joining them. So do the storage engine (InnoDB?) and other details. Why are you choosing an arbitrary chunk of fifteen log rows right after midnight 180 days ago? The more you tell SO, the more the folks here can help you.

Comment: It's MyISAM, because READ is more than write, I think MyISAM is 3x faster than InnoDB based on my local benchmarks. although `table lock` is another problem for each writing.

Comment: @TomTom I'm thinking about caching users into Redis.